# Calibrate touchscreen of external Monitor under wayland sway

Tags: wayland, touch-screen, sway

How do I calibrate the touchscreen of an external display under wayland - sway?

If I plug an external monitor with touch support the touch input is getting mapped to the main monitor, not the external one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get the input device with `swaymsg -t get_inputs`
2. get the monitor with `swaymsg -t get_outputs`
3. test with `swaymsg input <input> map_to_output <output>`
4. set in sway config file `input <input> map_to_output <output>`
5. do the same for the main display if it supports touch so

for me the command looked like the following:

`input "8146:32786:Siliconworks_SiW_HID_Touch_Controller" map_to_output DP-1`